# I want to take out integer from text

Tags: python

So, there some text that has integers in it, i want to take those out and put them in different list, but not together. 
example:

```
Sometext = somekindoftext123withthis445
numlist = (123,445)
```

i tried doing it with lists

```
nums = ("0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9")
```

but it rather puts these separately.

```
listi = []
num = []
while True:
  inputi = input("Text here: ")
  if inputi == "stop":
    break
  else:  listi.append(inputi)


for i in inputi:
  if len(inputi) > 0:
    listi.append(inputi)
while nums != 1000:
    if nums in listi[0]:
      num.append(nums)
```

Comment: You seem to be confusing lists and tuples. `(1, 2, 3)` is a tuple, `[1, 2, 3]` is a list. Variables should generally follow the `lowercase_with_underscores` naming convention, see [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for more on Python style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to find all occurrences of digits as the following:

```
import re
s = 'somekindoftext123withthis445'
nums = [int(x) for x in re.findall(r'\d+', s)]
print(nums)
# [123, 445]
```

However, if you don't want to use regular expressions and use loop instead you can do something like:

```
s = 'somekindoftext123withthis445'
num = 0
nums = []
ok = False
for c in s:
    if c.isdigit():
        num *= 10
        num += int(c)
        ok = True
    else:
        if ok:
            nums.append(num)
            num = 0
            ok = False
if num:
    nums.append(num)
print(nums)
# [123, 445]
```

Comment: This helped me, butcan you tell me what (num *=10) does?

Comment: @TLuna7 multiplies the number by 10 (num = num * 10), which is used to create the number digit by digit (0 * 10 + 1 = 1) (1 * 10 + 2 = 12) (12 * 10 + 3 = 123)

Answer (score 0):

Use a regular expression to match all the integers.

```
import re
sometext = 'somekindoftext123withthis445'
numlist = list(map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', sometext)))
print(numlist)
```

Answer (score 0):

A one liner solution:

```
print [i for i in Sometext if i.isdigit()]
```